# Iterating over XML and selecting specific element tree content

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML which looks like this:

```
<openie>
  <triple confidence="1.000">
    <subject begin="0" end="1">
      <text>PAF</text>
      <lemma>paf</lemma>
    </subject>
    <relation begin="1" end="2">
      <text>gets</text>
      <lemma>get</lemma>
    </relation>
    <object begin="2" end="6">
      <text>name of web site</text>
      <lemma>name of web site</lemma>
    </object>
  </triple>
  <triple confidence="1.000">
    <subject begin="0" end="1">
      <text>PAF</text>
      <lemma>paf</lemma>
    </subject>
    <relation begin="1" end="2">
      <text>gets</text>
      <lemma>get</lemma>
    </relation>
    <object begin="2" end="3">
      <text>name</text>
      <lemma>name</lemma>
    </object>
  </triple>
</openie>
```

The element `openie` is nested in here: `root>document>sentences>sentence>openie`

And in my function I am trying to print `triples` which each contain `subject, relation, object` elements. Unfortunately, I can not get it to work, since I am unable to get into these three elements and their `text` element. Which part is wrong?

```
def get_openie():
    print('OpenIE parser start...')
    tree = ET.parse('./tmp/nlp_output.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    for triple in root.findall('./document/sentences/sentence/openie/triple'):
        t_subject = triple.find('subject/text').text
        t_relation = triple.find('relation/text').text
        t_object = triple.get('object/text').text
        print(t_subject,t_relation,t_object)
```

Output for two triples should look like this:

`PAF gets name of web site`

`PAF gets name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your `t_object` you're running `triple.get()` instead of `triple.find()`. Changing that fixes your problem.

```
def get_openie():
    print('OpenIE parser start...')
    tree = ET.parse('./tmp/nlp_output.xml')
    root = tree.getroot()
    for triple in root.findall('./document/sentences/sentence/openie/triple'):
        t_subject = triple.find('subject/text').text
        t_relation = triple.find('relation/text').text
        t_object = triple.find('object/text').text
        print(t_subject,t_relation,t_object)
```